# How to match SSLCertificate to correct alias in keystore

Tags: java, ssl, dns, webserver

Hello,

I'm working on a personal project of creating a multi domain webserver in java.
Just for fun and understanding the underlying various mechanisms.

I'm now using a custom KeyManager that implements the X509KeyManager that loads all the domains certificates into one keystore and orders them by alias.
Below is the most importaint function that returns the alias of the requested domain.

```
    @Override
    public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            ExtendedSSLSession session = ((ExtendedSSLSession)((SSLSocket)socket).getHandshakeSession());
            return new String(session.getRequestedServerNames().get(0).getEncoded(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is what i'm using at this moment. But i'm reading also something about SNIMatchers and SNIHostNames and SNIServerNames.

If someone can help me understand this better and give an opinion if i'm implementing this right. Please let me know.
Thank you al in advance